# Discord реакции

Tags: python, discord

На сообщении ставят реакции, по реакциям отбирают список участников. Задача получить таблицу участников поставивших реакции на сообщении, которую можно редактировать. К примеру на сообщении стоит 32 реакции(вид реакции один, галочка например), нужна таблица из 32 участников, при возможности ее редактировании(потому что участников должно быть 20 и нужно убрать 12 участников).

У участников одна роль.

Перегуглил интернет, ничего полезного из существующих дискорд ботов не нашел, подскажите как решить проблему. P.s. Заранее спасибо:)

весь гугл и яндекс, хочу найти решение это или бот в дс или даже не знаю как.

Comment: реализуйте бота самостоятельно, если ничего не нашли. discord.py в помощь)

Comment: если вы хотите чтоб вам написали бота за вас, то вам нужно обратиться на любую площадку с фрилансерами, которые за ваши монетки сделают что вы желаете

Comment: разбейте свою задачу на мелкие подзадачи; 1 -  получить список кто поставил реакцию; 2 - редактирование таблицы;

Comment: тут для начала вопрос, это вообще осуществимо или нет